# Spark and Drools integration (Reading rules from a drl file)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, drools

I am working on a spark program that takes input from the `RDD` and runs a few drool rules on it reading from a drl file.

in the drl file i have made a rule that wherever the hz attribute of the object is 0 it should increment the `counter` attribute by 1.

I have no clue why is that not working, it gives me an output of 0 for all the data in the stream (Yes, there is data with hz attribute equal to 0 and yes, I can print all the attributes and verify that even for them `counter` is 0)

I am using the `KieSessionFactory` class that I found on a github project here https://github.com/mganta/sprue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudera/sprue/KieSessionFactory.java

But I am quite sure that this part not where the problem is, it only reads from the drl file and applies the rules.

below is my scala code: (I have marked the part where I think the problem lies, but please take a look at the drl file first)

```
package com.streams.Scala_Consumer

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.{ DStream, InputDStream, ConstantInputDStream }
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.avg
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.producer._
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{ Deserializer, Serializer }
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
import org.kie.api.runtime.StatelessKieSession
//import KieSessionFactory.getKieSession;
//import Sensor

object scala_consumer extends Serializable {

// schema for sensor data   
class Sensor(resid_1: String, date_1: String, time_1: String, hz_1: Double, disp_1: Double, flo_1: Double, sedPPM_1: Double, psi_1: Double, chlPPM_1: Double, counter_1: Int) extends Serializable
{
var resid = resid_1
var date = date_1
var time = time_1
var hz = hz_1
var disp = disp_1
var flo = flo_1
var sedPPM = sedPPM_1
var psi = psi_1
var chlPPM = chlPPM_1
var counter = counter_1

def IncrementCounter (param: Int) =
{
    counter = counter + param
}
}

// function to parse line of sensor data into Sensor class
def parseSensor(str: String): Sensor = {
    val p = str.split(",")
    //println("printing p: " + p)
    new Sensor(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3).toDouble, p(4).toDouble, p(5).toDouble, p(6).toDouble, p(7).toDouble, p(8).toDouble, 0)
}

var counter = 0
val timeout = 10 // Terminate after N seconds
val batchSeconds = 2 // Size of batch intervals

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val brokers = "maprdemo:9092" // not needed for MapR Streams, needed for Kafka
    val groupId = "testgroup"
    val offsetReset = "latest"
    val batchInterval = "2"
    val pollTimeout = "1000"
    val topics = "/user/vipulrajan/streaming/original:sensor"
    val topica = "/user/vipulrajan/streaming/fail:test"
    val xlsFileName = "./src/main/Rules.drl"

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SensorStream").setMaster("local[1]").set("spark.testing.memory", "536870912")
                                                                    .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
                                  .set("spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate", Integer.toString(2000000))
                                  .set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", Integer.toString(2000000));

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(batchInterval.toInt))

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
        ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> brokers,
        ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> groupId,
        ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG ->
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG ->
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG -> offsetReset,
        ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG -> "false",
        "spark.kafka.poll.time" -> pollTimeout
    )

    val producerConf = new ProducerConf(
        bootstrapServers = brokers.split(",").toList
    )

    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

    val values: DStream[String] = messages.map(_._2)
    println("message values received")
    //values.print(10)
///////////*************************PART THAT COULD BE CAUSING A PROBLEM**************************/////////////
    values.foreachRDD(x => try{
                                print("did 1\n")     //markers for manual and minor debugging
                                val myData = x.mapPartitions(s => {s.map(sens => {parseSensor(sens)})})
                                //myData.collect().foreach(println)
                                //println(youData.date)
                                print("did 2\n")
                                val evalData = myData.mapPartitions(s => {
                                val ksession = KieSessionFactory.getKieSession(xlsFileName)
                                val retData = s.map(sens => {ksession.execute(sens); sens;})
                                retData
                                })
                                evalData.foreach(t => {println(t.counter)})
                                print("did 3\n")
                               }

    catch{case e1: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => println("exception in line " )})
///////////*************************PART THAT COULD BE CAUSING A PROBLEM**************************///////////// 
    println("filtered alert messages ")

    // Start the computation
    ssc.start()
    // Wait for the computation to terminate
    ssc.awaitTermination()

}
}
```

the drl file

```
package droolsexample

import com.streams.Scala_Consumer.Sensor;
import scala.com.streams.Scala_Consumer.Sensor; //imported because my rules file lies in the src/main folder
                                            //and code lies in src/main/scala 

// declare any global variables here
dialect "java"
rule "Counter Incrementer"

when
    sens : Sensor (hz == 0)

then
    sens.IncrementCounter(1);
end
```

I have tried using an xls file instead of the drl file, I have tried creating the class in java and the object in scala. I have tried a lot of other things, but all I get in the output is a warning:

```
6/06/27 16:38:30.462 Executor task launch worker-0 WARN AbstractKieModule: No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase
```

and when I print the counter values I get all zeroes. Anybody to the rescue?

Comment: If a simple rule `rule x when then System.out.println( "Hello" ); end` is in that file and not firing then, most likely, you aren't creating the knowledge base correctly. Do you think that importing two different classes with the same simple name is a good idea?

Comment: I have tried importing them individually too. Also, I have tried just printing ("Hello") that didn't work either. I am sorry but I have no clue what knowledge base is, I would google it but if you have a link or resource I would be really grateful if you could post in here :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing the `spark` submit and passing your JAR for execution, pls ensure that other dependency JARs from KIE, etc are also included with in the same JAR and then run it with `Spark-Submit`.

alternate is to have two separate projects one where you have your `spark` program another is your KIE project so you will have two Jars and you run it something like below:

```
 nohup spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/log4j.properties" \
     --queue abc \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--jars drools-kie-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --class com.abc.DroolsSparkJob SparkcallingDrools-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
-inputfile /user/hive/warehouse/abc/* -output /user/hive/warehouse/drools-Op > app.log &
```